# Spring Data JPA retrieve entities where root field or list entity field matches criteria

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

The following entity relationship exists: `A 1 <-> * B` (*edited down for brevity*)

```java
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @Id
    UUID id;

    @Column
    String searchText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity_a", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<EntityB> listOfB;

}

@Entity
public class EntityB {

    @Id
    UUID id;

    @Column
    String searchText;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_a_id")
    EntityA entityA;
}
```

I would like to retrieve all entities (`EntityA`) where a specific field (`searchText`) matches a criteria - easy enough. Now I want to go through all linked entities (`EntityB`) with a field (`searchText`) matching the criteria as well, only returning the matching entities. This result can be in any format for eg:

- `Map<EntityA, List<EntityB>>` (The parent `EntityA`, possibly matching, with matching children `EntityB`)
- `List<EntityA_EntityBSearchResult>` (some custom domain model)
- `List<EntityA>` (bad: don't use entities with not conforming to expected relationship)

There are two main constrains complicating this

- The outer entity (`EntityA`) should stay pageable
- The resulting list (of `EntityB`) is limited to a maximum of 10 items

### What I've tried:

*Building the SQL before converting to JPA Query*
For simplicity the criteria is a simple `like '%textToFind%'` on field `searchText`

*1. Retrieve all of `EntityB` where `EntityA` or `EntityB` matches criteria.*

```sql
select a.*, b.* from entity_a a
    inner join entity_b b on b.entity_a_id = a.id
    where a.search_text like '%textToFind%' or b.search_text like '%textToFind%'
```

Good: Pageable on `EntityA`
Bad: `EntityB` not limited to max of 10 items. Grouping will have to be done afterwards to `Map<EntityA, List<EntityB>>`.

*2. Retrieve all of EntityB where `EntityA` or `EntityB` matches criteria - limited to 10 of EntityB.*

```sql
select * from entity_b where id in (
    select limitedB.id from (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.created_date_time DESC) AS RowNumber, b.* from entity_a a
            inner join entity_b b on b.entity_a_id = a.id
            where a.search_text like '%textToFind%' or b.search_text like '%textToFind%') limitedB 
            WHERE RowNumber <= 10)
```

Good: `EntityB` limited to 10
Bad: Not pageable on `EntityA`

*3. Retrieve all of `EntityA` first (where `EntityA` or `EntityB` matches criteria). Followed by retrieval of `EntityB` (where `EntityA` or `EntityB` matches criteria) with parent `EntityA` id in previous list.*

```sql
select DISTINCT a.* from entity_a a
    inner join entity_b b on b.entity_a_id = a.id
    where a.search_text like '%textToFind%' or b.search_text like '%textToFind%'
```

use the result to create an `EntityA` id list (`List<UUID> EntityA_Ids`). Send this list to the next query:

```sql
select * from entity_b where id in (
    select limitedB.id from (
        select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.created_date_time DESC) AS RowNumber, b.* from entity_a a
            inner join entity_b b on b.entity_a_id = a.id
            where a.search_text like '%textToFind%' or b.search_text like '%textToFind%') limitedB 
            WHERE RowNumber <= 10) and entity_a_id in EntityA_Ids
```

From this result a map (`Map<EntityA, List<EntityB>>`) can easily be created with `Collectors.groupingBy`.

Good: `EntityA` is pageable and `EntityB` is limited to 10
Bad: Multiple queries